# How to create a jsp page to display all the uploaded file names as downloadable links (in GAE Java)?

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I am trying to create a file sharing page in GAE where anyone can upload files and it will display the same file name as downloadable link.

I am able to upload file as blob and also I am able to serve it by passing the blob key.

```
blobstoreService.serve(blobKey, resp);
```

Also I am able to get all the blobkeys and file names.

```
     BlobInfoFactory blobInfoFactory = new BlobInfoFactory();
       Iterator<BlobInfo> blobInfoIter = blobInfoFactory.queryBlobInfos();
       while(blobInfoIter.hasNext()){      
           BlobInfo blobInfo =  blobInfoIter.next();
           BlobKey blobKey = blobInfo.getBlobKey();
           String blobKeyStr = blobKey.getKeyString();
           String fileName = blobInfo.getFilename();
       }
```

I can pass these file names to the JSP and display it, but how will I make those file names as downloadable link. How will I map those file names with the corresponding blobkey dynamically so that it can be downloadable?

Please advice if there is any good design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From docs:

> To serve blobs, you must include a blob download handler as a path in your application.

So, if you're using plain Servlets+JSP you need a Servlet with:

```
@Override
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res) throws IOException {
    BlobKey blobKey = new BlobKey(req.getParameter("blob-key"));
    blobstoreService.serve(blobKey, res);
}
```

and make a link like:

```
<a href="/myservlet?blob-key=${blobKeyStr}">${fileName}</a>
```

See official examples:

- https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/blobstore/#Java_Serving_a_blob
- https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/blobstore/#Java_Complete_sample_application